# Does drastic change in temperature affect static electricity

Tags: electrostatics

I have a doubt that 'does sudden change in temperature effects the activity of static electricity'. Maybe there is a relationship between heat and static but when the temperature increase or decrease suddenly does it affect the rate of static activity??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, if you're increasing the temperature, you're giving energy to the atoms. This means that the electrons now need less energy to escape from those atoms. Which would slightly increase electrostatic activity.